# PHP jQuery add field to list multiple fields

Tags: php, jquery

I got a code where you can add field inputs to a list, and then echo it out. What I'm looking for is a way of having a total of 3 fields. I not sure how to do it with the loop and so on, since the name of the field is the loop itself.

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
    $field_values_array = $_REQUEST['field_name'];

    foreach($field_values_array as $value){
        echo $value;
    }
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
    var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
    var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
    var fieldHTML = '<div><input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field"><img src="remove-icon.png"/></a></div>'; //New input field html 
    var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
    $(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
        if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
            x++; //Increment field counter
            $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field html
        }
    });
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
        x--; //Decrement field counter
    });
});
</script>

<div class="field_wrapper">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field"><img src="add-icon.png"/></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit: 3 inputs instead of one being echoed out at the same row, and will be looped out as one. Something like an array $array[0],$array[1],$array[2]

I tried this solution, but doesn't work:

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
    $field_values_array = $_REQUEST['field_name']." - ".$_REQUEST['field_name2']." - ".$_REQUEST['field_name3'];

    foreach($field_values_array as $value){
        echo $value;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you please ask more specifically. The code looks good to me it roughly does what you describe. What exactly is not working?

Comment: @mrfloden: Did you want 3 input field values on submit? Is this exactly you want?

Comment: @Apb I want it to be 3 inputs at start, then when I press "add" I want 3 inputs acting more like one. Since 3 inputs will be in one row in my database

Comment: @mrfloden: in one row or in one column? Could you please elaborate your question

Comment: @Apb My database is: "title", "price" and "taxes". What I want is each input will be in one of the rows

Comment: @mrfloden: are these 3 fields dynamically added? If title, price, taxes are 3 separate columns in your database then you can name your textboxes by column name and fetch them

Comment: But I cannot REQUEST more than once into the foreach

Comment: are these 3 fields dynamically added?

Comment: You want to add multiple records in a go wants to add all form for a record to form when user clicks `add_button` right?

Comment: I want 3 input to act like one, so I can have it in one variable. Then I want every "row of inputs" (when press add_button) to be looped as a variable, so I can print it etc

Answer (score 0):

This is how you loop through each value in a `$_REQUEST` and get all values where the name is equal to `field_name`.

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){ 
    foreach ($_REQUEST as $parent => $value) {  //Loop over $_REQUEST
        if($parent == "field_name")
        {
            foreach ($_REQUEST[$parent] as $key=> $item){
                //You can check if $item is empty
                if(!empty($item))
                {
                    echo "field_name[".$key ."] => ".$item."<br/>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var maxField = 10;
        //Input fields increment limitation
        var addButton = $('.add_button');
        //Add button selector
        var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper');
        //Input field wrapper
        var fieldHTML = '<div><input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field">X</a></div>';
        //New input field html 
        var x = 1;
        //Initial field counter is 1
        $(addButton).click(function(){
            //Once add button is clicked
            if(x < maxField){
                //Check maximum number of input fields
                x++;
                //Increment field counter
                $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML);
                // Add field html
            }
        }
                          );
        $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){
            //Once remove button is clicked
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            //Remove field html
            x--;
            //Decrement field counter
        }
                     );
    }
                     );
</script>
<form>
    <div class="field_wrapper">
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field">Add</a>
            <button name="submit" type="submit">
                Send values
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

[image: Display]

[New full source demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/b983-g0x1)

Comment: @mrfloden Is this what you need?

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/index.php on line 12
fieldname=>Array

That's the error I got. I need the $_REQUEST to get the info from the input field, which I can't

Comment: I am assuming that your `fieldname` values are indexed.Check demo. print_r($_REQUEST) before the loop and show me.

Comment: $_REQUEST["field_name"]; //For testing only (Needs to be removed!)
$_REQUEST["field_name2"]; //For testing only (Needs to be removed!)
$_REQUEST["field_name3"]; //For testing only (Needs to be removed!)
    foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {  //Loop over $_REQUEST
        $x="";
        if (strstr($key, 'field_name')) {
            $x = str_replace('field_name', '', $key); 
            echo "fieldname".$x."=>".$value."<br/>";
        }
    }

Comment: That's my code, since I need to REQUEST the values from the inputs

Comment: also, it only prints the first

Comment: I don't know what demo you are running. Are you saying that when you click run on my demo link that it only display 1 value?

Comment: No, what I mean is that when I run the code and trying to make it work with the code in my first question, it doesn't print more than one "row".

Comment: Ok this is a string `NOT` an array: `$field_values_array = $_REQUEST['field_name']." - ".$_REQUEST['field_name2']." - ".$_REQUEST['field_name3'];`

Comment: `array_push($field_values_array,$_REQUEST['field_name'],$_REQUEST['field_name2'],$_REQUEST['field_name3']);`this is how you add values to an array

Comment: if you do a print_r(REQUEST); after adding values to array the format should look like this: `Array ( [field_name] => test A [field_name2] => test B [field_name3] => test C )`

Comment: That line gives me this "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '‌​' (T_STRING) in"

Comment: `$field_values_array = array($_REQUEST["field_name"],$_REQUEST["field_name1"],$_REQUEST["field_name2"]);`

Comment: Same problem as before

Comment: @mrfloden i have updated my demo with ALL the code. check it out

Comment: @mrfloden You should accept the answer if it solve your problem, so that others with similar question can see that the answer is valid.